# spring boot application and mysql in one kubernetes pod

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes-pod

I want to maintain my spring boot application and mysql in one pod. I've tried with separate pods for each one and it's working fine. I want to bind both into single pod. how can i achieve that?

Comment: What is your motivation to do that?

Comment: that is my requirement, and they are isolated from other services ( independent )

Comment: What is the reason for that requirement, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Just like @Thomas stated, depending on what you're trying to achieve, this [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1004534/954950) should be useful.

Comment: Running two services in one pod is a bad idea 99.999% of the times. The containers of a pod are guaranteed to run on the same node - so your application and your SQL server will compete for resources when the load gets high. "that is my requirement, and they are isolated from other services" This can be achieved in a much more scalable way by means of [NetworkPolicies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/)